# How to Push Data into SAP which can create a general Ledger using REST

Tags: java, spring, sap-erp, netweaver, sap-pi

I've zero knowledge on SAP, requirement is, in SAP system there should be an end point which receives a REST request which should be able to create General ledger / store in database using SAP NetWeaver technology.

Found SAP JCo felt its not appropriate.

1. Can SAP provide Rest End point Consuming JSON data for POST Body ??
2. if any jars available to transform data or connection to SAP system using Java.

Help me for such kind of scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Natively SAP doesn't support REST request and given that JCo is not an option, few solutions can be applied (all of which imply some developments in SAP):

1. Using PO 7.5 middleware (if available), which can process incoming REST requests through its adapter and convert the request in WS-SOAP for SAP

client -> PO (with rest adapter) -> SAP (receiving SOAP XML)

2. Using SAP Netweaver gateway (if available in your SAP version)
3. SAP can receive requests through HTTP protocol. Via transaction SICF you can define a new service with the custom logic you need.